# How to add custom label to Gnuplot graph legend?

Tags: gnuplot

In a graph I'm making with gnuplot I draw some grey lines (`set arrow` command), which represent the physical boundaries of my experiment (i.e., walls)

I would like to know how I can add this information on the legend of the graph, so it says "Walls" and have a grey line next to it.

I thought about creating a new series that contained this information, but I was wondering if it's possible to explicitly add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add information directly to the legend.  You can, however, either draw the legend explicitly, or plot a line which will not appear within the range of the plot, e.g.

```
plot [][0:1] 2 lc rgb 'gray' t 'Walls'
```

Or, if your x and y limits are already set:

```
...
[set x and y limits here]
...
plot 1e20 lc rgb 'gray' t 'Walls'
```

Comment: I was just about to post this... You probably should add a ` title "Walls"` in there somewhere ...  Also note that `plot NaN lc rgb "gray" title "Walls"` will also work (and guarantee that it isn't in range).

Comment: @iomartin -- it worked without setting the range?  That surprises me ... I just meant that it would work no matter what range you set.  What version of gnuplot are you using?

Comment: @mgilson - My mistake. I forgot I'd already set the xrange and yrange for my other series in the same plot.

Comment: @mgilson: good point, I added the title to the `plot` command as you suggested.  I usually have trouble with `plot NaN` but I realized it works as long as there is something else on the plot.

Comment: @andyras : `plot NaN` works as long as the xrange and yrange are set *somehow* -- Either through a previous `plot` command, or explicitly with `set xrange [min:max]; set yrange [min:max]`

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to note: since plotting a single line tended to mess up a graph of mine, a better solution for me was to plot a single point; but as found in [Plotting single points « Gnuplotting](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-single-points/), that is kinda difficult (especially if insertion at arbitrary plot legend/key position is needed) - unless redirection is used... This is what worked for me:

```
plot "filename" using 1:8 \
,\
... # more plot lines here
,\
"<echo '-1 -1'" lc rgb 'white' with points title '---' \
,\
... # more plot lines here
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to make the name of the data file the legend which you want and then plot that data file.